# Populate textbox based on combobox selection

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am looking to update a textbox based on a combo box selection.

For example:
If someone selects the word "Beach Holiday" from the drop down, then the text box will automatically populate with the word "Spain"

How do I do that?

I know I can do something similar to:

```
me.textbox = me.combo.column(1)
```

but that's not exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also trying this in VBA: If Combo47 = "P01" Then
Me.Text52 = "Policy"
Else
' nothing
End If

Comment: Have _two_ columns for each row in the combo: `"Beach Holiday";"Spain"`

Comment: Thank you - For it to update, do I put the VBA in Form updates? As that aint working, but does work when I put it in On Click

Comment: I sorted it thank you - I put it after update for the combo

Answer (score 1):

Configure your ComboBox to have two columns, with the width of the second column set to `0` so that it is not displayed.

Then, set the `Control Source` of your Text Box to

```
=[YourComboBox].Column(1)
```

The value of the Text Box will then automatically update without the need for Event handlers.