# Access:How do I auto populate a field when I change the value in a combo box in a form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that allows the user to change pieces of information in a table. I would like the user to be able to select a name from a combo box and the related email address to auto populate.  I have a table with the names and associated email addresses.

This seems so simple but I'm a lost newbie...

Comment: Options: 1) include address info as column of combobox and then expression in textbox references combobox column `=comboboxname.column(1)`; 2) include lookup table in form RecordSource and bind textbox to email field with Locked Yes and TabStop No; 3) VBA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populate textbox based on combobox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305833/populate-textbox-based-on-combobox-selection) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002326/populate-textbox-from-combobox or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365567/concat-combobox-choices-into-textbox